# Allowing exactly one thread to pass / not making threads wait unnecessarily

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight

First off, let me explain the situation...

I have a class that has 2 properties: DataA and DataB; it doesn't matter what they are, what is important is that each can be calculated from the other. I'm in a multithreaded environment and want DataA / DataB to be calculated when and if it is necessary (it's not always the case that both will be accessed). My first thought was something like...

```
public SomeDataObject DataA
{
    get
    {
        if (dataAisAvailable)
        {
            return dataA;
        }
        else
        {
            if (dataBisAvailable)
            {
                lock (dataACalcLock)
                {
                    // Don't want other threads recalculating dataA
                    if (dataAisAvailable)
                    {
                        return dataA;
                    }

                    ////////////////////////////////
                    // Calculate dataA from dataB //
                    ////////////////////////////////

                    dataAisAvailable = true;
                    return dataA;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this pattern, assuming that dataB is indeed available, the first thread arriving on the scene (let's call it thread1) goes in and calculates dataA, all good so far... However, any threads that have been waiting around for dataA to be calculated now have to access it one-by-one... not very efficient imho. I'd like to have these threads waiting for thread1 to finish calculating dataA, and then all go for it as though there is no lock.

I've had other thoughts with ManualResetEvents perhaps, but I'm not sure how I can safely ensure that one and exactly one thread passes through to do the calculation.

I hope I've explained that clearly, although I'm not convinced that I have. Happy to clarify though...

**EDIT:** My bad, I'm on .NET 4.0. And this is in Silverlight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by a comment on my question which was subsequently removed, I checked out `Lazy<>` and went with something similar to...

```
    static SomeDataObject DefaultData;

    private Lazy<SomeDataObject> dataA = new Lazy<SomeDataObject>(() => DefaultData, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
    private Lazy<SomeDataObject> dataB = new Lazy<SomeDataObject>(() => DefaultData, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    public SomeDataObject DataA
    {
        get
        {
            return dataA.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            dataA = new Lazy<SomeDataObject>(() => value, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
            dataB = new Lazy<SomeDataObject>(GetDataB, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
        }
    }
    public SomeDataObject DataB
    {
        get
        {
            return dataB.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            dataB = new Lazy<SomeDataObject>(() => value, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
            dataA = new Lazy<SomeDataObject>(GetDataA, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
        }
    }

    private SomeDataObject GetDataA()
    {
        if (DefaultData == dataB.Value)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////
        // Calculate dataA from dataB //
        // and return it.             //
        ////////////////////////////////
    }
    private SomeDataObject GetDataB()
    {
        if (DefaultData == dataA.Value)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////
        // Calculate dataA from dataB //
        // and return it.             //
        ////////////////////////////////
    }
```

Unfortunately ReaderWriterSlimLock wasn't available in Silverlight, otherwise it looked promising. A little bit of benchmarking suggested that the above is by far and away quicker (not to mention doing more what I wanted) than anything I'd written myself.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds pretty much like the scenario for which [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) was invented (multiple concurrent readers allowed, while only one thread at a time is allowed to write).

It could look like something along these lines (didn't verify this code properly, so make sure it works as you want it to should you decide to use it):

```
private ReaderWriterLockSlim dataLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public SomeDataObject DataA
{
    get
    {
        if (dataAisAvailable)
        {
            return dataA;
        }

        dataLock.EnterReadLock();

        try
        {
            if (dataBisAvailable)
            {
                dataLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();

                try
                {
                    // Don't want other threads recalculating dataA
                    if (dataAisAvailable)
                    {
                        return dataA;
                    }

                    dataLock.EnterWriteLock();
                    try
                    {
                        ////////////////////////////////
                        // Calculate dataA from dataB //
                        ////////////////////////////////

                        dataAisAvailable = true;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        dataLock.ExitWriteLock();
                    }

                    return dataA;
                }
                finally
                {
                    dataLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            dataLock.EnterReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

*Tip/plug:* if you want to cut down a bit on the amount of added try/finally constructs, you can wrap some of that in extension methods ([as presented in my blog](http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2010/03/07/Using-extension-methods-to-hide-infrastructure-code.aspx)), or perhaps even cleaner by wrapping it in an `IDisposable` proxy ([as suggested by Josh Perry](http://curiouslynerdy.com/2011/04/hiding-readerwriterlockslim-housekeeping-in-a-using-statement/)).

Comment: Thanks for the code, much appreciated. Looks like I can't use this in Silverlight though... which is annoying. (Aware I didn't mention that before, sorry!)

Comment: Also, just wondering here: does acquiring the write lock force other threads to wait at the EnterReadLock()?

Comment: @Simon: no, any number of threads can hold a read lock. Only one can acquire an upgradeable read lock or a write lock, so these are the spots where threads might be put on hold. The only occasion when threads will be kept waiting for a read lock is when another thread is holding a write lock.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
if (dataAisAvailable)
        {
             //Wait for AutoResetEvent here, perhaps add a timeout and when it expires, you can return the current dataA, so threads don't wait forever. 
            return dataA;
        }
        else
        {
            if (dataBisAvailable)
            {
                lock (dataACalcLock)
                {
                    // Don't want other threads recalculating dataA
                    if (dataAisAvailable)
                    {
                        return dataA;
                    }

                    ////////////////////////////////
                    // Calculate dataA from dataB //
                    ////////////////////////////////

                    dataAisAvailable = true;
                     //Set AutoResetEvent to signalled so waiting threads can get to DataA.
                    return dataA;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Threads arriving while dataA is being calculated will not reach the ResetEvent as dataA will NOT be available until thread1 has finished calculating it...

Answer (score 0):

To be sure - what you want to do is avoid recalculating A and B while avoiding locks when accessing them after the first calculation, Yes?

If a thread reads dataAisAvailable and finds it true, then there is no problem - the thread can use A.  If it reads dataAisAvailable and finds it false, then there is a problem and it needs to acquire an exclusive lock to ensure that dataAisAvailable is still false and calculate it if so.  A critical section would do, I think. If A/B take ages to calculate, this will fall back to a kernel lock, but this would only happen first time a thread found one of the booleans false.

I think you can get away with this because the booleans only ever go 'one-way', from false to true, and so you can get away with a simple boolean check, (I think ).

Your 'thread 1' will find dataAisAvailable false and so attempt to acquire the lock.  If it succeeds, it checks dataAisAvailable again inside the lock and either calcualtes it or not.  It then exits the lock, returning dataA.  If 'thread 2' gets in first, in between thread 1 checking dataAisAvailable and thread 1 acquiring the lock, calculates dataA and exits the lock, thread 1 will then enter the lock, find dataAisAvailable is now true and so just exit the lock with dataA.

Threads 2-N will then always see dataAisAvailable as true and get A without attempting to acquire the lock at all.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: The situation I'm worried about is a large number of threads arriving between thread1 entering the lock and dataA becoming available. These threads will then all be waiting to enter the lock and will then acquire the lock and return dataA one-by-one. It's the performance issue with them acquiring the lock and accessing one-by-one that concerns me...

Comment: Maybe I'm just being ott though... Oh, and yes, what you've described is exactly the case...